# How to remove currency symbol, when formatting currency using Globalizejs library?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-globalize

I am using [Globalizejs](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize) to format Currency based on Logged-In user details in my application.

I don't want currency Symbol to be displayed when formatting is done using below code snippet:

```
Globalize.locale( "en" );
currencyFormatter = Globalize.currencyFormatter( "USD", {
  maximumFractionDigits: 0,
});

currencyFormatter(parseInt(totalCost.amount));
```

which returns

> **$1,212,122,112** for amount: **1212122112**

Is there any option similar to `maximumFractionDigits` to avoid the currency symbol ?

Comment: Is `totalCost.amount` a variable from server or from user? Note that you should use parseNumber if it's from user (since it could be localized).

Comment: Are you intentionally using `parseInt`, i.e., is amount an integer and you would be stripping off any potential fractions available there. PS: If it's the amount of cents I would expect decimal shift by dividing the amount by a factor of 10^x.

Comment: @RafaelXavier Yes totalCost is an Object which I am getting from the Server.

Comment: Why is it a string and not a number already? Is it a string representing a POSIX number or a localized number?

Comment: I am getting this data from an API call to which I have no or less control, hence it's in the String format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `Globalize.numberFormatter`

Longer answer: Two benefits of using currency formatter is: (a) have the currency symbol properly formatted, and (b) have the appropriate number of fraction digits properly formatted; note that several currencies such as USD, EUR, have 2 fraction digits by default, but others like JPY have 0, there are different cases too.

The appropriate solution to customize the markup and style of a formatted output is to use parts `Globalize.currencyToPartsFormatter`: At the time we speak, this feature isn't implemented yet https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/issues/679.

As a workaround, which should work fine for your specific use case (no currency symbol + integers only amount), using `Globalize.numberFormatter` should suffice.

Comment: When are you planning to implement mentioned feature `Currency format to parts #679` 
Are you saying there is no difference between **currencyFormatter** and **numberFormatter** apart from the *currency Symbol* ?

Comment: No, as written above, currencyFormatter also figures out the default fraction digits of the requested currency. There is no roadmap for 679, but PR is welcome and should be accepted.

Comment: okay, thanks. will try to create the PR....... one more question Is there a way to configure the currencyFormatter to show the currencySymbol as prefix, not as a suffix?

Comment: No by design. Prefix/suffix depends on the locale

Comment: @NeerajJain in general, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, indeed i was able to complete my task with NumberFormatter